# How to do a custom bookmarks post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, bookmark

### Let me first explain what I am wanting to do...

I am wanting to add all my hundreds of website bookmarks that I have now in my browser, into wordpress for the following reasons.

- Can search my bookmarks by tags
- Can search my bookmarks by description and/or name
- Can access my bookmarks from anywhere
- Can add a description to all my bookmarks
- Can add a screenshot image of website (optional)
- Will have a custom template for viewing the bookmarks which will look different from a regular blog post/list

### And what I have done so far...

- Created a new post type **"Website Bookmarks"** with the code below

functions.php

```
<?php
/*
*  Add custom post type
*  name: website_bookmarks
*/

function bookmark_post_type()
{
    // Set some labels for our bookmarks post type
    $bookmark_labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Website Bookmark', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Websiteite Bookmark', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Websiteite Bookmark'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Website Bookmark'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Website Bookmark'),
        'new_item' => __('New Website Bookmark'),
        'all_items' => __('All Website Bookmarks'),
        'view_item' => __('View Website Bookmark'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Website Bookmarks'),'not_found' => __('No website Bookmarks found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Website Bookmarks found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Website Bookmarks'
        );

    $bookmark_args = array(
        'labels' => $bookmark_labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'bookmark',
            'with_front' => false),
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag', 'category'),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'can_export' => true,
        'supports' => array(
            'post-thumbnails',
            'thumbnail',
            'excerpt',
            'custom-fields',
            'editor',
            'title'
        )
    );
    
    register_post_type('website_bookmarks', $bookmark_args);
}

add_action('init', 'bookmark_post_type');
```

---

### And then what I need help/ideas with...

I basically need the following...

- Website Title
- Website URL
- Website Description
- Bookmark Tags (can be more then 1) This will be done with a custom taxonomy
- Screenshot image (can be optional)

So...

I can use the built in **post title** for the **website title**,

Website URL ? Should I use custom fields for this?

Website description ? Again custom fields or something else like the content input box?

Bookmark tags, done with custon taxonomy

Screenshot image ? should I just use the post thumbnail for this?

Please help, this will be my first time using wordpress do do any kind of custom stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i would go about it:

- Website Title - **Post title.**
- Website URL -  **custom field.**
- Website Description - **post content (editor).**
- Bookmark Tags  - **custom taxonomy.**
- Screenshot image  - **Post thumbnail.**

Seems simple enough.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use the built in bookmarks post functionality. If you click on the Links menu, it already has everything you want and more at your fingertips.

You can read more about Bookmarks template tags here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bookmarks

Check out this thread as well for using bookmarks in your template: [Is there an easy way to create a links index page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29049/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-a-links-index-page/29052#29052)

Comment: Screenshot image is one that's not possible built in bookmarks. The built in bookmarks post functionality is one of the most under used feature.

Comment: There is a field to identify an image for each link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Links feature built into wordpress,

If your feeling adventurous, you could attempt to persuade Michael Fields to give you his code:

http://wordpress.mfields.org/bookmarks/ ( proof of what could be done )

But plugin wise, I don't think there is anything worth noting out there at the moment. Most people are happy to build their own solution, or just use the built in Links.

**edit:** this may be of use: http://wpranks.com/user-bookmarks-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Yup - I've often had the same thought, but never got around to implementing it.  I do every now and then export my bookmarks (just in case)

This "press it" bookmarklet could be useful (drag onto toolbar)
http://codex.wordpress.org/Press_It

Also a worked example:
http://www.famousbloggers.net/tdo-mini-forms-bookmarking-thesis.html

and this one, using a wordpress get_bookmark function
http://www.devlounge.net/code/how-to-use-wordpress-for-bookmarking

Let us know how you go.  I'd be interested to know what you decided.

Answer (score 0):

Bookmarks Custom Post Type
or Wordpress

https://github.com/aaronpk/Wordpress-Bookmarks

Store bookmarks as a custom post type in Wordpress.

See a demo here: http://links.aaron.pk